# Tree or other data structure most efficient to lookup "recent searches"

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I thought there exists a tree algorithm for what I'm now looking for, but I forgot about it's name and Googling didn't help there.

I'm searching for an algortithm that has the very best lookup performance for a data. Characteristics:
- Each lookup is expected to be a hit. So all keys which are looked up exist (there may be some misses, but these will be treated as a "misconfiguration", and the occurrence of such misses is negligible)
- It is very likely (the data set is optimized for this) that same lookups occur subsequently - e.g.  there are likely to be a million lookups for key 123, there may be a single lookup for key 456 in between, and then again millions of lookups for 123. Then later a next group with likely same keys are looked up, and so on

Sure I could use a hash algorithm. But for the given purpose I remember that there was a search optimized tree, which optimizes lookups in such way that most recent lookups are at the very top of the tree. so potentially you'd have the first node of the tree directly a hit O(1), without needing a hash function or modulo of an hash store.

I'm seeking this algorithm to achieve raw performance for graphics rendering on mobilde devices.

Comment: Such a tree would have to reorder itself on every lookup (unless it frequently made the same most-recent lookup), which would at best take time comparable to a call to the hash function.

Comment: Why not use a simple heap with search counter? You could store it in an array, and perform normal linear search. Increase the counter of searched key and upheap it. This should work well for very unbalanced search patterns. @chepner Such tree would not need to reorganize on each look-up, it would need to update itself, yes but it's fast, and reorganize occasionally.

Comment: Move to front lists could be of help for your setting.

Comment: Have you looked at caching strategies, e.g. LRU caching strategy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree).

> A splay tree is a self-adjusting binary search tree with the additional property that recently accessed elements are quick to access again.

But a hash table would be expected O(1), so you shouldn't expect the one to clearly outperform the other.

Comment: Formally, the unproven [dynamic optimality conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree#Dynamic_optimality_conjecture) states that splay trees are O(1)-competitive, which would mean that every sequence of tree operations could be done in runtime within a constant factor of any other possible dynamic binary search tree

Comment: Thanks! The Splay Tree was indeed what I tried to remember.

Comment: I think @Niklas B. is right - I'd change the tree a bit in such way that the most recebt searches travel up quicker to the root. It will for my purpose have also O(1) for the always-expected best case, minus hashing and modulo (millions of times just hitting the root node by a simple comparison ).

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because this was what I forgot about and askes for. Though only after bendhmarking I'll see what fits best for me - likely Niklas suggestion works well or even better.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a hash table for the job. To speed up subsequent searches, you can cache the K most recently accessed, different elements in an array. If K is small (< 20 or so), linear search in that array will be very fast, because it can stay in the L1 cache.

Comment: I was thinking about such small cache as well. I have no idea how this will behave in reality on a memory constrained smartphone, but will also definitely benchmark this. Upvoting for likeley good if not best choice